# Get image src links from urls using perl and store in DB

Tags: perl

I am trying to extract image src links using the following Perl code. Don't get where I am making mistake.
 1. open a file and read URLs in it

My text file looks like this

```
https://zzzzzz.com/
https://yyyyyyy.com/
https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://www.google.com/
https://www.yahoo.com/
```

2. `foreach` URL in text file extracting img src
3. print the retrieved data into another file
4. again open the file using new file handle and read it into an array
5. while dereferencing array it shows error `ARRAY(0x2e14a48) ARRAY(0x3125528) ARRAY(0x312e170)`.

Perl code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::LinkExtor;

my $filename = "/path/to/file";

open FILE, '<', $filename or print "cant open file: $!";
my @data = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

my $image = "/path/to/file";

open FILES, '>', $image or print "cant write to file: $!";

foreach my $urls (@data) {
   my $url = get("$urls");

   my $linkextor = HTML::LinkExtor->new( \&links );

   $linkextor->parse($url);

   my $key;

   sub links {
      ( my $tag, my %links ) = @_;
      if ( $tag eq "img" ) {
         foreach my $key ( keys %links ) {
            if ( $key eq "src" ) {
               foreach my $da ( @{$links{$key}} ) {
                  if ( $da =~ /^[a-zA-Z]/ ) {
                     print FILES "$da;\n";
                  } #if
               } #foreach
            }    #if
         }    #foreach
      }    #if
   }    #sub

   print FILES "\n";

}    #foreach
close(FILES);
```

Until this, there is no problem I got all the src links like

```
https://zzzzzz.com/;https://yyyyyyy.com/;https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/;

https://zzzzzz.com/;https://yyyyyyy.com/;https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/;

https://zzzzzz.com/;https://yyyyyyy.com/;https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/;

https://zzzzzz.com/;https://yyyyyyy.com/;https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/;
```

This is the format I have output in the text file, all I need is to insert all these urls by order as `$image1, $image2, $image3` in image column

```
my $platform = "mysql";
my $database = "xxx";
my $host     = "xxxxx";
my $port     = "xxxx";
my $user     = "xxxxx";
my $pw       = "xxxxxxxxx";

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:$platform:$database:$host:$port", $user, $pw );

open FILED, '<', $image or die "cannot open file: $!";
my @img = <FILED>;
close(FILED);

foreach my $lin (@img) {
   chomp $lin;
   my @in     = split ';', $lin;
   my $image1 = $in[0];
   my $image2 = $in[1];
   my $image3 = $in[2];

   print "$image1 $image2 $image3 \n";

   $sth->execute( $li, $val, $parsed, $htmls, $image1, $image2, $image3 );

}

exit;
```

I thought that I am making mistakes in foreach loop, am I right. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... why do you have a sub definition embedded within your foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely here:

```
foreach my $da ( $links{$key} ) {
```

Because it looks like you're assuming that `$links{$key}` is an array, when it cannot be - it can *only* be an array reference. And this will have the problem you described if you print it - it'll out put `ARRAY(0xDEADBEEF)` type format, because that's how an array ref stringifies.

So you *might* find that changing it to:

```
foreach my $da ( @{$links{$key}} ) {
```

Will do the trick.

But I'd also suggest

- embedding a sub within a foreach loop is bad style.
- Use 3 argument open with lexical file handles - e.g. `open my $input, '<', 'file.name' or die $!`.
- iterate that with a `while` loop, rather than reading it into an array that you don't then reuse.
- you declare `my $key` twice - the first instance isn't used, and is misleading.
- You write your output to `$image` as `FILES` and then you open the same file and read it back in again. You don't seem to need the intermediate file though, so why not just stash it in the `@img` array in the first place?

Comment: It's also worth noting that `@data` should be `chomped`, although I think `LWP::Simple` ignores trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

your problem lies here.

```
my @in     = split ';', $lin;
my $image1 = [0];
my $image2 = [1];
my $image3 = [2];
```

You are assigning the anonymous array to your variable. Above line should be like this.

```
my $image1 = $in[0];
my $image2 = $in[1];
my $image3 = $in[2];
```